# Virtual Machine managed identity access token refresh after permission change

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-managed-identity

This question is regarding VM managed identity token caching. Especially when the permission of the managed identity is changed, will the token cached on the VM be invalidated immediately such that the token retrieved after the permission change is most up to date and reflecting the current permission granted to the managed identity. If the invalidation is not automatic, is there a way to force it by user manfully? Is there any document on the supposed behavior?

Some details of our use scenario and testing:
We are using managed identity assigned to a Azure virtual machine either system assigned or user assigned to query Graph API. The access token is retrieved via local IMDS endpoint. We encountered some strange behavior probably related with the access token caching.

Scenario one:

1. Permission is NOT granted to the VM managed identity
2. Retrieving the access token and querying the graph caused 403 error, which was expected.
3. Granted the permission to the managed identity
4. Repeat step 2, the operation still failed with the same error.

Scenario two:

1. Permission is granted to the VM managed identity
2. Retrieving the access token and querying the graph succeeded, which was expected.
3. Remove the permission from the managed identity
4. Repeat step 2, the operation still succeeded.

Scenario three:

1. Permission is granted to the VM system assigned managed identity
2. Retrieving the access token and querying the graph succeeded, which was expected.
3. Remove the system assigned managed identity itself from the VM
4. Repeat step 2, the operation still succeeded.
5. Only after restarting the VM, we then failed to retrieve the access token from this logically non-existent managed identity via IMDS.

Could anybody shed some light on this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are cached in various infrastructure systems, and it can take several hours (up to one day) to see changes reflected in a token.

See [Limitation of using managed identities for authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identity-best-practice-recommendations#limitation-of-using-managed-identities-for-authorization) for details.